# How to get URL parameter via Joomla api with decoded strings?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api, url

how can I get the full url parameter with the url-encoded values

```
?myParam=dummy%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%BC
```

this is the decoded url:

```
?myParam=dummyöäü
```

if I use

```
$myText = urldecode(JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('myParam'));
```

the encoded or directly entered umlauts are missing in my var myText

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `string` filter instead of the default `cmd` filter:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('myParam', '', 'string')
```

Or:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->getString('myParam')
```

Comment: what do you mean with default cmd filter?

Comment: When no filter is specified, `cmd` is used. So `$input->get('myParam')` equals `$input->get('myParam', null, 'cmd')`. It strips out characters such as umlauts.